# Two tables, distinct values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
tbl_expenses
sitename 
amount


tbl_payment
sitename 
amount
```

How to get distinct sitename and amount as a SUM from those two tables?

Comment: Hint a join ,sum() and group by

Answer (score 0):

If you want just distinct value then use below query-

```
select distinct sitename,amount from tbl_expenses
UNION 
select distinct sitename,amount from tbl_payment
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
select 
distinct(sitename) 
from tbl_expenses 
inner join tbl_payment 
on tbl_expenses.sitename=tbl_payment.sitename;
```

Comment: Please give explanations in your answers. See [How to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select sitename,SUM(amount) from tbl_expenses 
 inner join tbl_payment
 on tbl_expenses.sitename=tbl_payment.sitename
 group by sitename
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method using `union all` and aggregation:

```
select sitename, sum(expense) as expense, sum(payment) as payment
from ((select sitename, amount as expense, 0 as payment
       from tbl_expenses
      ) union all
      (select sitename, 0 as expense, amount as payment
       from tbl_payment
      )
     ) ep
group by sitename;
```

Your problem is more subtle than you might think.  You want to be sure that all sites are included in the output, even if the site only appears in one table.  You also have to be careful with cartesian products, which is why a `join` is not the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT sitename, SUM(amount) sum_amount FROM
(
  SELECT sitename,amount FROM tbl_expenses
  UNION ALL
  SELECT sitename,amount FROM tbl_payment
) A
GROUP BY sitename
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sitename, sum(amount) from (
  select sitename, amount from tbl_expenses
  union
  select sitename, amount from tbl_payment
) test group by sitename
```